# Getting a list from the first record from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table named costumer. Those customers have evolutions where I take notes from contacts that are made.

So the costumer table will have the basic information and the the evolutions will have what it needs and a field to point out the customer. Let's say costumer_id.

This will be a One to Many relation and I need to export several CSVs from mysql with a list of the clients when the first evolution was created (evolution.created_at) for a given month.

Been going around and I can't make the query work. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do a select that looks something like this:

`SELECT 
c.customer_id 
min(e.created_at)
FROM 
costumer c 
inner join evolution e on
e.costumer_id = c.costumer_id
-- Not sure what you mean by given month
where e.month = 'April'
group by c.customer_id`

Comment: I think he might want MIN() instead of MAX().

Comment: yes you are right because he wants the first evolution. i corrected the query above

Comment: What I meant by the given month is something like: MONTH(created_at) = X
But that aside can I make that min(e.created_at) a where condition?

Comment: Yes you could for example use `HAVING min(e.created_at) = 12.12.2012`